# similar string from two data frame with a count number

Tags: r

I have two data that I am trying to find similar strings between them with their position.

```
df1 <- structure(list(split = structure(c(7L, 6L, 8L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 9L, 
4L, 9L, 5L, 10L, 1L), .Label = c("America1", "corea", "coreanorth1", 
"gdyijq", "gqdtr", "india-2", "india1", "india3", "udyhfs", "USA"
), class = "factor"), count = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 5L, 5L)), .Names = c("split", "count"), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), class = "data.frame")
```

it looks like this

```
split       count
india1        1
india-2       1
india3        1
coreanorth1   2
corea         2
gdyijq        3
udyhfs        3
gdyijq        4
udyhfs        4
gqdtr         4
USA           5
America1      5
```

I have another data with the same structure,

```
df2<- structure(list(split = structure(c(3L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("America1", 
"gdyijq", "india1"), class = "factor"), count = 1:3), .Names = c("split", 
"count"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))



    split    count
   india1     1
   gdyijq     2
 America1     3
```

I want to check whether from df2 any string exist in df1 and put the count with a comma seperated for example

india1 is in the df2 and is similar to india1 in df1, so the output is

```
india1  1,1
```

if it appears more than once, each time with a semicolon seperated like 
gdyijq

The output looks like below

```
india1     1,1
gdyijq     2,3;2,4
America1   3,5
```

Answer (score 3):

you want something like merge or join from dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
(DF <- inner_join(df1, df2, by = "split")
```

Now we have to combine all entries for one split:

```
DF %>%
  group_by(split) %>%
  summarize(counts = paste0(count.x, ",", count.y, collapse = ";"))
```

Results in

```
# A tibble: 3 × 2
     split  counts
     <chr>   <chr>
1 America1     5,3
2   gdyijq 3,2;4,2
3   india1     1,1
```

Comment: what does this warning `mean Warning message:
In inner_join_impl(x, y, by$x, by$y, suffix$x, suffix$y) :
  joining factors with different levels, coercing to character vector` and how do you export it? when I do this, it gives me quotation `""` `write.table(myDF, file = "DF.txt", sep = " ",row.names = FALSE)`

Comment: Do you know how factors work in R? Basically it means that there are elements in `df1$split` that are not in `df2$split` and the column split in the result is now character instead of factor. And I don't quite understand your second point. Do you mean you don't want quotation marks in `DF.txt`? Try `quote = FALSE`.

Answer (score 2):

This will not give you the exact result, but it will list in a data frame all matches and the count values for each:

```
z = merge(df1,df2,by = "split")
```

Result:

```
> z

     split count.x count.y
1 America1       5       3
4   gdyijq       4       2
5   gdyijq       3       2
8   india1       1       1
```

Comment: In my opinion this is a better format than what the OP asked for.

Comment: I think so too. The original format forces the column to be in a string format which may be hard to work with.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a possible data.table version:

```
library(data.table)

# convert to data.table
df1 <- as.data.table(df1)
df2 <- as.data.table(df2)

# set keys for use in matching
setkey(df1, split)
setkey(df2, split)

# chain operations
# match values in df1 using df2; 
# then paste the counts (i.count from df1)
# merge row using split as group (i.count: count from df2)
df1[df2][ , .(split, count = paste(i.count, count, sep =",",  collapse=";")), by = split]
```

Output is something like this:

```
      split  counts
1: America1     3,5
2:   gdyijq 2,3;2,4
3:   india1     1,1
```

Comment: You can have both `sep` and `collapse` in the same `paste` call, like `df1[df2, on=.(split), allow.cartesian = TRUE, nomatch=0, paste(i.count, count, sep=",", collapse=";"), by=.EACHI]`

Comment: Thanks! Finding my way with data.table =D

Comment: Use `setDT` instead of `as.data.table` to avoid a copy. And use `df1[df2, on = .(split)]` to save yourself the trouble of the two `setkey()`s. Oh, and you don't need the `split` (in `.(split, count = ...)`), the group column is always in the output.

Comment: Btw. I can't try it atm. but shouldn't it just work if you put the join and the paste in a single data.table call: `df1[df2, .(count = paste(...)), split]`?

Comment: Thanks for pointing those (figured that out while playing with data.table more). I'm not sure with the last comment though; the `df1[df2]` should do the merging, which adds a new column.